# Nginx accesslog for LiipImagineBundle images

Tags: symfony, nginx, liipimaginebundle

I have the LiipImagineBundle installed in my Symfony2 2.1.10 installation and I experience a little configuration problem with my nginx server. On the net I discovered [this nice snippet](http://ihaveabackup.net/2012/11/17/nginx-configuration-for-symfony2/) as a great and simple nginx configuration for Symfony2 apps. I added some lines of code. Most importantly I want to be able to disable the `access.log` for static files like images.
The following ruleset was working flawlessly:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
}
```

But today I discovered that images generated by the LiipImagineBundle need to be accessed via the `app.php` or the `app_dev.php`. Otherwise they don't get generated and nginx logs the following error message:

```
[error] 28988#0: *733 open() "/[...].jpeg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Which is basically a 404. The file doesn't get generated because it is not accessed via the Symfony2 application but directly.

I need a configuration that allows me to disable the access-logging and adding some caching headers to static files, but still serve them through the same route as before.

Is there a possible solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. I've created a regex that matches bot `app.php`/`app_dev.php` and `png|jp[e]g|gif` etc. Now images are cached as requested. If an Image was not generated the server responses with `201 Created` and afterwards with either `200 Ok` or `304 Not Modified` depending on wether it was cached before or not.
Here is my corresponding nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/(app_dev|app)\.php(.*?)\.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 18h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;

    # still redirect because we are using LiipImagineBundle!
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}

# more static files:
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 18h;
    add_header Cache-Control "publi, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/(app_dev|app)\.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice job! Mind if I add it to my repo? :)

Comment: Of course not! Feel free to use it. :) Maybe you can even optimize it?! I am not sure if my regex is the fastest possible.

Comment: @Inori I discovered this [security issue](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/). I'm not sure but I think it might apply to this configuration.

Comment: Note a typo in `publi`

Comment: Your solution didn't worked to me. The caching headers is not included in the reponse. Can you show your whole configuration?